# How to retrieve the value of eval_metrics in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a working pipeline that train a model and evaluate metrics (defined in `EstimatorSpec`). I can also see the aggregated value of metrics (for instance, `accuracy`) in Tensorboard.

Now I would like to calculate some business quantity as a function of aggregated eval_metrics for the entire evaluation dataset. (as a made-up example, consider `f(accuracy)=sqrt(accuracy)`).

But I don't know how to retrieve the tensor of accuracy in the first place. I tried 
`tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("accuracy:0")` and I get

```
"The name 'accuracy:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'accuracy', does not exist in the graph."
```

Do I miss anything?

Thanks